# how to sort an array of strings alphabetically with angular orderBy filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a model that contains a list of countries

```
$scope.model = {
    name: "foo",
    countriesVisited: ["CA", "AR", "GB", "FR", "MX", "AU", "IE", "RU", "IT", "ES", "IN", "US", "NL", "DE", "CL", "BR", "JP", "NZ", "PL"]
  }
```

Using an ng-repeat directive lists them in the order they are shown.
Putting an orderBy filter does order the items, but the order is seemingly random.  See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9CXAkATMRIXTsEC2kO2)

Remove the filter and watch the output shift.  Paste it back and it's in a weird order.

Is there a way to get the countriesVisited array to order without moving it to it's own $scope variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="country in model.countriesVisited | orderBy:'toString()'">
```

Comment: Since values are already strings, isn't there a less greedy way to sort them? I'm just curious

Answer (score 2):

Change your orderBy to orderBy: 'toString()'. Primitives don't sort by default, but you can pass in a function as we are doing here.

Comment: ok - to clarify, this is converting each item in the array from a string type to a string object, correct?  Why is it that primitives do not sort by default?  I have read about the difference between string and String but never come across it in practice before - Thanks for the help!

Comment: The orderBy filter is expecting an object. Check out the documentation at [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). You'll see three options are available for the expression: a string of the value to sort on, function, or an array of string or functions.